# How to make pop up using colorbox.js on anchor click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, colorbox

I have a hierarchy module which creates a table of which on anchor tag click i want to make a pop with the value related to that field.but in my code it doesn't step inside .click in jquery. In my view
[image]

As you can  see the hierarchy is dynamically created but on click in employee or 8 it does not step inside my function.

My code:

```
sb.Append("<div class='sfGridwrapper'>");
sb.Append("<table class='positiontable'>");
sb.Append("<thead><th>position name</th><th>poscount</th></thead>");
sb.Append("<tbody>");
foreach (var item in a)
{
    string[] words = item.Split('_');
    sb.Append("<tr>"); 
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        sb.Append("<td>");
        sb.Append("<a href='Javascript:void(0);' class='Popup'>")
        sb.Append("<span data-departname="+ word + " class='popupmembers'>");
        sb.Append(word);
        sb.Append("</span></a></td>");
    }
    sb.Append("</tr>");
}

sb.Append("</tbody></table></div>");
```

In my jquery:

```
$('.positiontable').on('click', '.popupmembers', function () {
    alert('hello');
    var getPositionName = $(this).closest('td').siblings().eq(0);
    var getDepartmentName = $(this).parents('a').find('span').eq(0).text();
    Hierarchy.GetEmployeeValues(getPositionName, getDepartmentName);
    $(this).colorbox({
        inline: true, 
        href: '#employeeValue',
        closeButton: true,
        onClosed: function () { $('#employeeValue').hide(); }
    });
});
```

The div that needs to be pop up is

```
 StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder();
        stb.Append("<div id='employeeValue'></div>");
        LiteralControl literal = new LiteralControl(stb.ToString());
        PlaceHolderEmployee.Controls.Add(li);
```

I need help to step into my function in jquery. Can anyone point out where i am doing mistake.

Comment: since the question is about client side scripting, post the rendered html than server side code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('Body').on('click', '.popupmembers', function () {
    alert('hello');
    var getPositionName =$(this).closest('td').find('td:eq(0)').Text();
    var getDepartmentName = $(this).parents('a').find('span').eq(0).text();
    Hierarchy.GetEmployeeValues(getPositionName, getDepartmentName);

    $.colorbox({
        inline: true,
        href: '#employeeValue',
        closeButton: true,
        onClosed: function () { $('#employeeValue').hide(); }
    });
});
```

I have made a new Js file and initialize with all the required parameter then placing the code in new js just worked for me as well as the colorbox just made popup of my data.